# How to put html content between links using the wp_nav_menu function

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The title pretty much says it all. What I want to do is be able to place a custom bullet point before each of my links, apart from the first. Is there a way I can open up the wp_nav_menu(); loop and add content in there?

This is my nav:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'head_nav' , 'menu_class' => 'header_nav' ) ); ?>
```

It is basically output like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

but I want this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><div class="custom_bullet"></div><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><div class="custom_bullet"></div><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><div class="custom_bullet"></div><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: here's what I want]

Comment: You can probably do this through CSS and no WordPress functions. What does this _"custom bullet"_ look like?

Comment: @hungerstar I was thinking of using :before{content: ""} but I need a coloured bullet with rounded corners. You think this is possible?

Comment: Can you add an image of the bullet to your post please?

Comment: @hungerstar done

Comment: Yes, it is possible with CSS. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make square bullets with rounded corners you make a square element and apply `border-radius`. This can be accomplished with pseudo elements instead of adding additional markup with `wp_nav_menu`. Color the bullets with `background-color`. Make adjustments as needed.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

ul li::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

ul li:nth-child(1)::before {
  background-color: indianred;
}
ul li:nth-child(2)::before {
  background-color: gold;
}
ul li:nth-child(3)::before {
  background-color: seagreen;
}
ul li:nth-child(4)::before {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but would I be able to make it a square with rounded corners?

Comment: @hungestar Awesome! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use "before":
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

```
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'theme_location' => 'head_nav', 
        'menu_class' => 'header_nav',
        'before' => '<div class="custom_bullet"></div>'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: This would display a bullet before all links... OP doesn't want the first link to have a bullet so you would have to add custom CSS rule to hide the first bullet... A CSS only solution would be a much better option in this case.

Comment: I agree that css only solution is better, but my answer is directly for the question. He wants to add div element before every link and presented code do exactly this. Your statement is not true. Value in the "before" key is placed before each link, not whole list. Why downvote then?

Comment: I reread your comment and I must say that i doesn't fully understand it at first. Right is yours.

Answer (score -1):

You can add classes to each `li` through Wordpress. 
Here's how: https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/adding-css-classes-wordpress-menu/

That way you can add the `class="custom_bullet"` that you need.

Also, as hungerstar proposed, `:before` can do the trick

Comment: This would display a bullet before all links... OP doesn't want the first link to have a bullet so you would have to add custom CSS rule to hide the first bullet... A CSS only solution would be a much better option in this case.